# Copies of the reals in $\mathbb{C}$ without the Axiom of Choice

Tags: fields, axiom-of-choice, automorphism-groups, galois-groups

Suppose we work in a model in which the Axiom of Choice does not hold, and in which $\mathbb{C}$ only has one nontrivial automorphism (such models exist).

**Question**: *"how many" subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?*

More precisely: in what way does the size of the automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}$ influence/control this question?

Comment: It is consistent that there are no such subfields other than $\mathbb R$ itself, but I don't know if it happens in every model in which there are no nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: Just for context, under AC, the answer is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}=2^c$. (The reason is (a) that the automorphism group has this cardinal, and (b) acts on the set of such subfields with $\mathbf{R}$ having a stabilizer of cardinal 2, so its orbit has cardinal $2^c$.)

Comment: I have a feeling that I recently (last few months?) saw this question somewhere online. Odd.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Wasn't me :-)

Comment: By the way, a related question is: how many subfields are isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}$. Under AC, the answer is again $2^c$. In general, the "algebraic closure" map from the set of subfields isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$ to the set of subfields isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}$ is surjective.

Comment: @YCor, does one have any information about the fibres of the "algebraic closure" map on the set of subfields isomorphic to $\mathbb C$?  (I guess surjectivity is obvious, since every subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ can have the copy of $\mathbb R$ inside the 'honest' $\mathbb C$ transported to it along the isomorphism.)  Or do you prove that the cardinality of such fields is $2^{\mathfrak c}$ by some other means?

Comment: @LSpice All fibers of this map have the same cardinality, since all fields isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ will have the same number of copies of $\mathbb R$ which make it an algebraic closure. I believe all of these copies of $\mathbb R$ form one orbit under the automorphism group of $\mathbb C$, whose size is half the size of the automorphism group.

Comment: Hmm, now I realise I don't understand @YCor's earlier [remark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387105/copies-of-the-reals-in-mathbbc-without-the-axiom-of-choice#comment987113_387105).  Certainly the automorphism group of $\mathbb C$ acts on embeddings $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$, but why does it act transitively?  If $s$ is the standard embedding and $i$ is any other, then $i$ extends to an embedding of $\overline{i(\mathbb R)}$ into $\overline{s(\mathbb R)}$ (under AC), but why does it extend to an automorphism of $\overline{s(\mathbb R)}$?

Comment: @LSpice I never said it acts transitively. Under AC, it doesn't and they are as many orbits as isomorphic copies of $\mathbf{C}$ in $\mathbf{C}$.